# Finding bases for which a number is a strong pseudoprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Find the number of bases $a$ such that a number 1073 is a strong pseudoprime to this base.

Can I get the number of bases without actually getting the bases (without knowing the explicit value of the bases)?

I was given a number (1073) and I were supposed to find all bases so that the number 1073 is a strong pseudoprime to the base. I managed to find some (6 different bases) but I am not sure that I found them all. To check that I am correct, a way to find just the amount of bases would be useful. Is it possible?

Comment: My quick check only gives the base $191, 302, 771, 882,\;$ although 
http://oeis.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprimes lists the (IMO incorrect) additional base $260,813.$ I just asked this here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720049/is-n-1073-a-strong-pseudoprime-to-bases-a-260-813.  I do not think
that is possible to get the **exact** number of base, but there are some
statistics used to estimating the failure 'probability' of probable primes
tests.

Comment: Thx, depending on the definition I added to my 6 bases also numbers 1 and 1072, so actually, I have also 4 - the same as you have. So I would say that the OEIS is wrong

Comment: In special cases, the number of bases can easily be calculated, for example the case $n=(4k+3)(8k+5)$ , where $4k+3$ and $8k+5$ are primes, we have $\frac{\phi(n)}{4}=2(2k+1)^2$ such bases, while for $n=(4k+3)(8k+7)$, there are even only $4$ bases $a$ with $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$.

Comment: The Miller-Rabin test uses the fact that at most $\frac{1}{4}$ of the bases coprime to $n$ are SPRP-bases.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bases to which a number $n$ is a strong pseudoprime can be calculated:

With the factorization
$$n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i}$$
the number of bases less than $n$ including $1$ and $n-1$ is
$$\left(1 + \frac{2^{k\nu}-1}{2^k-1}\right) \prod_{i=1}^k\gcd\left(d,\ p_i^{'}\right)$$,

Where

- $d$ is the largest odd divisor of $n-1\quad$ ($n-1 = d \cdot 2^s$),
- $p_i^{'}$ the largest odd divisor of $\ p_i - 1$,
- $\nu_2(p_i) $ is the exponent of 2 in the prime factorization of $p_i-1\quad$ ($ p_i - 1 = 2^{\nu_2(p_i)} \cdot p_i^{'} $),
- $\nu$ is the minimum of all $ \nu_2(p_i)$.

Reference:
https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1986-46-173/S0025-5718-1986-0815848-X/S0025-5718-1986-0815848-X.pdf On the number of false witnesses for a composite number, p. 270 (5.4)

There is also an algorithm for calculating all bases to which a given number is a strong pseudoprime. It is described in
https://digitalcommons.iwu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1024&context=math_honproj New Implementations for Tabulating Pseudoprimes and Liars.pdf.