# Is $n=1073$ a strong pseudoprime to bases $a=260, 813?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

The OEIS Wiki page http://oeis.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprimes says that 
$n=1073\,$ is a strong pseudoprime to bases $a=260, 813.$

I think this is an error. $n=1073$ would be a strong pseudoprime to base $a=260$ if
(using the decomposition $n-1=d\cdot 2^s, 1072=67\cdot2^4$) we have
$$a^d \equiv 1 \pmod n$$
$$x_r \equiv a^{d\cdot 2^r}\equiv -1 \pmod n \quad \text{for some} \quad 0\le r < s$$
But for $a=260\;$ I get
$$a^d \equiv x_0 \equiv 260^{67}\equiv 260 \not \equiv \pm 1\pmod n$$
$$x_1 \equiv 260^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$$
$$x_2\equiv x_3 \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

For $a=813$ the analogous computations give 
$$x_0\equiv 813 \pmod n, \quad x_1 \equiv x_2 \equiv x_3\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

This shows that, that $1073$ **is not** a strong pseudoprime to bases $260, 813.$

> **Question:** Is this proof correct (if not, where is the error) and OEIS is incorrect?

PS: I stumbled on this during commenting on 
[Finding bases for which a number is a strong pseudoprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719229/finding-bases-for-which-a-number-is-a-strong-pseudoprime)

Comment: I have checked your arithmetic, and I agree that neither of these is a strong pseudoprime to base $1073$.

Comment: It's much easier to see that $260$ and $813 = 1073 - 260$ aren't bases for which $1073$ is a strong pseudoprime if you use the factorisation $1073 = 29 \cdot 37$. Now $260 \equiv 1 \pmod{37}$ and $260 \equiv -1 \pmod{29}$, so $260^{2k} \equiv 1 \pmod{1073}$ and $260^{2k+1} \equiv 260 \pmod{1073}$. Same argument for $813$.

Answer (score 0):

I have (re)checked it myself and really, there should be just numbers (191,302,771,882) working as bases for number 1073. So OEIS is wrong.